# When an iOS app is transferred to another owner does it remain in the same sandbox on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-sandbox

I am transferring ownership of an iOS app in the App Store to another owner.  The app saves user settings and other files in the local sandbox on the iOS device.  My question is if the app changes ownership will the sandbox where the app lives change when the app is updated?  Thanks.